# Trying to be able to click through transparency

Tags: c#

I have a filled image on my form in front of everything but most of it is transparant so i'm trying to click through it. I have this:

```
        public class clickThrough
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongW")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtrW")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

        private delegate IntPtr WndProcDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static WndProcDelegate SetWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, WndProcDelegate newWndProc)
        {
            IntPtr newWndProcPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(newWndProc);
            IntPtr oldWndProcPtr;

            if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                oldWndProcPtr = SetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, -4, newWndProcPtr);
            else
                oldWndProcPtr = SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, -4, newWndProcPtr);

            return (WndProcDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(oldWndProcPtr, typeof(WndProcDelegate));
        }
    }

    private void guna2PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int initialStyle = SetWindowLongPtrW(this.Handle, -20);
        SetWindowLongPtrW(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
    }
```

I get this error: The name 'SetWindowLongPtrW' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Override `CreateParams` instead of using `SetWindowLongPtr`. A layered, transparent Window is *untouchable*.

Comment: The error is saying you don't have a function with the name `SetWindowLongPtrW`, which is true.  You have two versions to choose from, either `SetWindowLongPtr32` or `SetWindowLongPtr64`.

Comment: @Jimi like this?: https://imgur.com/a/QCnN5rv
doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Idle_Mind Not sure if this is what you mean: https://imgur.com/a/Rz2I1H5 
getting same error

Comment: `CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams; parms.ExStyle |= (0x00080000 | 0x00000020);`. As already mentioned, you cannot touch that Form.

Comment: In your second picture the method with the error is OUTSIDE of the class containing the API declarations....

Comment: @Idle_Mind So it has to be inside like this?: https://imgur.com/a/WO8aMc3
I'm sorry if i'm misunderstanding i'm new to this.